# Не работает роутинг на сайте

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Сделал многостраничный сайт на React, поставл react-router-dom. Залил на хостинг.
При переходе по ссылкам внутри приложения, всё работает замечательно. Но при перезагрузке страницы или вводе адреса (кроме стартовой страницы) - выводит:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /team/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an
> ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Я понимаю, что необходимо настроить точку входа через один файл - index.html
Подскажите, как это лучше всего сделать.

Comment: Используйте create-react-app (CRA)

Comment: Совет выше не решит вашей проблемы, create-react-app никак тут не поможет. Ошибка в том, что данные запросы не обрабатываются у вас на сервере. Т.е. если вы заходите по адресу /team/ то сервер, как минимум ищет файл /team/index.html на файловой системе. Вам необходимо настроить Apache, что бы все подобные запросы приходили на файл index.html (.htaccess файл)

Comment: Если апач попробуйте - https://pastebin.com/54g2ZavD добfвить в .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

В конфиге веб-сервера на хостинге должно быть правило которое при отсутствии файлов и каталогов по пути на который указывает URI вернет HTML страницу с веб-приложением.

В случае Nginx конфиг (обычно рассоложенный в /etc/nginx/conf.d/) для сайта с react-router должен быть таким:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    root /srv/www/example.com;
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; # Вернуть файл, директорию или index.html если они имеются
    }
}
```

В случае сервера Apache нужно добавить в кофниг (обычно тут /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf) следующее:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com

  <Directory "/srv/www/example.com">
    ...
    RewriteEngine on
    # Если по переданному пути в URI файлы или каталоги существуют то сервер вернет их содержимое
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Если существующих файлов не найдено то сервер вернет содержимое index.html
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

В обоих примерах конфигураций подразумевается, что index.html это веб-страница с react-router находящаяся в /srv/www/example.com.

Comment: А что если у автора вопроса не nginx? Ваш ответ окажется бесполезным. Добавьте для апача

Comment: Спасибо, дополнил, только я использую nginx и пример конфигурации я взял и из своего сервера, а вот конфиг для apache мной не протестирован. Но ошибок быть не должно.